MYSQL join query taking long to fetch even a single row
    SELECT
        obo.id, obo.ready_notified, obo.view_notified, obo.order_name,
        CONVERT_TZ(obo.submitted_at, 'GMT', 'America/New_York') AS submitted_at,
        obo.order_counter, obo.is_pos, obo.occasion, obo.dine_in_table_number,
        obo.cashier_id, obo.terminal_name, obo.terminal_id, obo.payment_type,
        obo.total, obo.is_paid_by_split, obo.payment_type_raw, obo.is_submitted,
        obo.is_cancelled, obo.is_split_cancelled,obo.has_refund, obo.has_adjustment, 
        obo.adjusted_total, obo.tip,
        obo.refund_total, obo.refund_pending, obo.order_hash,
    GROUP_CONCAT(oth.transaction_id) AS transaction_id
    FROM
    order_botorder obo
LEFT JOIN order_ordertransactionhistory AS oth ON obo.id = oth.bot_order_id
WHERE
    obo.store_id = 407
    AND obo.is_open = 0
    AND (obo.is_submitted = 1 OR obo.is_closed = 1)
    
            and (   
                CAST(obo.id AS CHAR) LIKE '%tr_7AcXLYxUSK6K0WBVshqg1g%' 
                OR obo.phone_number LIKE '%tr_7AcXLYxUSK6K0WBVshqg1g%' 
                OR obo.order_counter LIKE '%tr_7AcXLYxUSK6K0WBVshqg1g%' 
                OR obo.dine_in_table_number LIKE '%tr_7AcXLYxUSK6K0WBVshqg1g%' 
                OR obo.delivery_address LIKE '%tr_7AcXLYxUSK6K0WBVshqg1g%' 
                OR obo.occasion_raw LIKE '%tr_7AcXLYxUSK6K0WBVshqg1g%' 
                OR obo.terminal_id LIKE '%tr_7AcXLYxUSK6K0WBVshqg1g%' 
                OR obo.cashier_id LIKE '%tr_7AcXLYxUSK6K0WBVshqg1g%' 
                OR obo.payment_type_raw LIKE '%tr_7AcXLYxUSK6K0WBVshqg1g%' 
                OR obo.total LIKE '%tr_7AcXLYxUSK6K0WBVshqg1g%'
                OR oth.transaction_id LIKE '%tr_7AcXLYxUSK6K0WBVshqg1g%'
            )
GROUP BY
    obo.id
ORDER BY
    obo.submitted_at DESC
LIMIT
    10 OFFSET 0;

here is the explainnation of the query it is almost searching data in 285384 that should not happen



id
select_type
table
partitions
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
filtered
Extra




1
SIMPLE
obo
NULL
ref
PRIMARY, order_botorder_order_counter_store_id_d14a38a1_uniq, order_botor_id_43a8b8_idx, order_botorder_order_hash_6c7414b4, idx_order_botorder_occasion, idx_order_botorder_phone_number, idx_order_botorder_order_counter, idx_order_botorder_dine_in_table_number, order_botorder_server_id_id_a2196482_fk_auth_user_id, idx_submitted_at, order_botor_is_subm_7011be_idx, order_botor_has_sub_df4837_idx, order_botor_is_clos_dfa4b1_idx, order_botor_is_tab__25acbe_idx, order_botor_is_pos_7954a9_idx, order_botor_is_onli_8f9a5f_idx, order_botor_submitt_736eb5_idx, idx_orderbotorder_id, idx_is_cancelled, idx_occasion, idx_optimized_query, idx_obo_store_id, idx_obo_submitted_closed_open, idx_obo_id, idx_obo_phone_number, idx_obo_order_counter, idx_obo_dine_in_table_number, idx_obo_occasion_raw, idx_obo_terminal_id, idx_obo_cashier_id, idx_obo_payment_type_raw, idx_obo_total, idx_fulltext_order_details
idx_optimized_query
6
const, const
285384
100.00
Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort


1
SIMPLE
oth
NULL
ref
idx_bot_order_id, order_order_bot_ord_baf3b4_idx, idx_oth_bot_order_id
order_order_bot_ord_baf3b4_idx
4
order_api_migration.obo.id
1
100.00
Using where; Using index




....phone_number LIKE '%tr_7AcXLYxUSK6K0WBVshqg1g%'  and What's the longest possible worldwide phone number.  Answer: "15 characters"  Conclusion: no phone_numbers can  make a match

@Luuk I'm assuming the value is coming from an input-field. Yes, you could skip searching the phonenumber for '%tr_7Ac...' but I don't think it will help much in the grander scheme. Also, fun fact: longer (than 15 digits) phonenumbers actually do exist in the wild even though 'spec' says it shouldn't. Germany uses longer numbers for example (See  Google's libphonenumber's Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Phone Numbers; number 16).

How many rows does the table have? How many rows do you get for store_id = 407? How many for store_id = 407 and is_open = 0?

@ThorstenKettner there are 80160 row matched with
SELECT
count(obo.id)
FROM
order_botorder obo
LEFT JOIN order_ordertransactionhistory AS oth ON obo.id = oth.bot_order_id
WHERE
obo.store_id = 407
AND obo.is_open = 0
AND (obo.is_submitted = 1 OR obo.is_closed = 1);
and value in coming from an form field which can filter in all the needed columns

@ThorstenKettner when i only join the table this fetch data fast but when i add condition in where condition to search using like query it takes time do i need to share something with you guys

@ankit251096 What don't you understand about my explanation here?

Please post the results for select count(*) from order_botorder, select count(*) from order_botorder where store_id = 407 and select count(*) from order_botorder where store_id = 407 and obo.is_open = 0.

@ankit251096: If you have an index on submitted_at, it is very easy to get the top 10 rows. If you want the top 10 matching certain conditions, however, then you'll have to find those rows first. No surprise hence that adding the conditions slows down the query.

You're using LIKE('%something%'), many times actually, which means that MySQL has to do a full table scan because it can't use indexes (yes, I will nuance later in this post).
Imagine I hand you a phonebook for your country and ask you to give me all contacts matching 'smi%'. Then you browse to S -> M -> I and start reading all names (Smith, Smither, Smith-Jones, ...).
Now imagine I hand you the same phonebook and ask you to give me all names matching '%mit%'. Now you have no option to go through all individual names in the phonebook from the very first to the very last to check if it matches '%mit%'.
What you're doing is even worse: You're not only looking for names matching '%something%' but also addresses, phonenumbers, everything, and the kitchen sink.
Now, to nuance this a bit: if the phonebooks were divided into books per city (in your case a store) that would make your job easier; you wouldn't have to go through cities you're not interested in. So you could start by adding an index on 'city' (in your case 'store').
I quite sure indexing on the is_<something> fields won't do very much (assuming they're all boolean 0 or 1 values) because of very low cardinality. But it may help.
What you want to do is to 'get rid of' as many rows as you need to scan before actually scanning. Adding an index on obo.store_id (if not already present) will help because that, essentially, will split the phonebooks into cities (stores); then all you need to do is grab the cities (stores) you're interested in and scan those. As per Luuk's suggestion you can also 'get rid of' a lot of rows by first telling MySQL you're not interested in rows from/before/after some date, which can then be indexed, or any other expression. Indexes on those fields will usually help - but don't go overboard adding indexes on every field; it will help in searching for stuff but it will also make inserts and deletes slower because indexes need to be updated on mutations of your data.

This is true, so I tried to suggest to limit the number of records (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78626031/724039 ) which needs to be searched.   In this case an index on store and submitted_at.

@Robill when i only join the table this fetch data fast but when i add condition in where condition to search using like query it takes time do i need to share something with you guys

@ankit251096 My post explains in great detail why the LIKE makes your query slow and gives you at least two options to try help make it faster (besides the obvious not using %<something> to search for values, so actually 3). What else do you want?

@ankit251096: When you are too lazy to read this answer, and you only expect full working code, where you do not have to think about, you can try removing this from your query, and see how that improves speed: CAST(obo.id AS CHAR) LIKE '%tr_7AcXLYxUSK6K0WBVshqg1g%' OR 

@RobIII: I am going to delete my answer (because it is not good enough to help here... )

@Luuk Don't. It added value. And I referred to it as well.

@RobIII: Ok undeleted it

Try indexing obo.is_open, obo.store_id, obo.is_submitted and obo.is_closed. You can check this : https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_create_index.asp
Indexing should improve performance in join queries

w3schools has a rather bad reputation. And what exactly are you proposing? Separate indexes on the four columns? Or one index combining the four? In the latter case: in which order? Why do you emphazise improvement in join  queries? Don't appropriate indexes generally improve performance?

The explain says Using filesort, and it does do that on 285384  rows. this is needed because it should be known which 10 rows are the first.
Becasue you have this:
WHERE
    obo.store_id = 407
    AND obo.is_open = 0
    AND (obo.is_submitted = 1 OR obo.is_closed = 1)

The index (probably idx_submitted_at) is not used.
In stead an index with the name idx_optimized_query is used, because MySQL thing that is the smarter approach to find this data.
EDIT:
Because this is all about selecting the correct info, you can try (not tested, because I do not have your data, and exact index definitions...)
In your SQL you do:
ORDER BY
    obo.submitted_at DESC
LIMIT
    10 OFFSET 0;

This means that you want to select the last 10 rows ordered by submitted_at.
When you add this to your WHERE clause:
AND obo.submitted_at >= (SELECT MIN(submitted_at) 
                         FROM order_botorder
                         ORDER BY submitted_at DESC
                         LIMIT 10 )

It could be that MySQL decides to use an index on submitted_at, when   that exists, and your final result should select less records than the current 285384, which means the filesort is quicker.

Hi Luuk, Thanks for you comment i don't have much experience on MYSQL can you please provide me the step by step solution, what should i do to resolve this problem

added an possible solution

The proposed solution looks very wrong. You'd look up the last 10 submitted rows and return them only when they happen to match the LIKEs. The original query looks for rows matching the LIKEs and returns the last 10 submitted of these instead.

oops, missed that .... .  But limiting the number of records through filtering out the data you definitely will not use (read: those from more than x years ago...) would never hurt.

when i only join the table this fetch data fast but when i add condition in where condition to search using like query it takes time do i need to share something with you guys
